# How to remove someone else play store console access from my account?

Tags: google-play

I have my own play store account.

Our client shared their account on my email id to publish their application on their account.

but after sometime client is not available or we are not working anymore with them and we are not in touch with them too. So now we don't need access to their play store console.

For that, I don't find any option to remove access of play store console from my end.

Do you guys have any solution on this?

(I don't remember their email id and we are not in touch with those client anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible right now, but I will feed this through as a feature request to the relevant people.